# Why does Vertx Event Bus block under high load?

Tags: java, netty, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I'm trying to send lots of messages over the Vertx event bus like this (Clustered with Hazelcast) without blocking:

```
EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  vertx.setPeriodic(1, num -> {
    eb.send("clusteredEndpoint", "ping");
  });
}
```

When the number of timers is smaller it works fine but at around 100 timers I get this error.

I'm wondering how to scale to 100K events/s without blocking (for reference I wrote a Vertx WebSocket test that could exceed this number).

If it's not possible I'd like to understand what's blocking - looks like it's something in this class: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/impl/clustered/Serializer.java

For references - this code does not block - even with 1000 timers:

```
HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
client.webSocket(8080, "localhost", "/", res -> {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    vertx.setPeriodic(1, num -> {
      res.result().writeTextMessage("ping");
    });
  }
});
});
```

> Dec 15, 2020 10:54:38 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
> WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been
> blocked for 36794 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
> io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked  at
> io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.addListener(FutureImpl.java:140)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.addListener(PromiseImpl.java:23)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.onComplete(FutureImpl.java:133)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
> at
> io.vertx.core.spi.cluster.impl.selector.Selectors.withSelector(Selectors.java:48)
> at
> io.vertx.core.spi.cluster.impl.DefaultNodeSelector.selectForSend(DefaultNodeSelector.java:42)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ClusteredEventBus$$Lambda$1065/195695453.accept(Unknown
> Source)   at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.Serializer$SerializerQueue$SerializedTask.process(Serializer.java:147)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.Serializer$SerializerQueue.checkPending(Serializer.java:94)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.Serializer$SerializerQueue.add(Serializer.java:114)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.Serializer.queue(Serializer.java:65)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ClusteredEventBus.sendOrPub(ClusteredEventBus.java:172)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.OutboundDeliveryContext.next(OutboundDeliveryContext.java:127)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.sendOrPubInternal(EventBusImpl.java:394)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.sendOrPubInternal(EventBusImpl.java:400)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.send(EventBusImpl.java:103)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.send(EventBusImpl.java:97)
> at io.vertx.example.EBtestClient.lambda$start$0(EBtestClient.java:22)
> at
> io.vertx.example.EBtestClient$$Lambda$1056/1487417027.handle(Unknown
> Source)   at
> io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:939)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:910)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:52)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:294)    at
> io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:24)    at
> io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.emit(AbstractContext.java:49)  at
> io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:24)    at
> io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.run(VertxImpl.java:933)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:176)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)     at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Note: your WebSockets code is not equivalent to your EventBus code. Equivalent would be if you open a websocket inside your callback, even with caching @tsegismont mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my analysis after further investigation:

When using the Vertx event bus for remote communication once the consumer gets overwhelmed it stops responding. This causes the producer to block and I've captured 3 different blocking messages (see below). After the blocking warning there's this warning:

> WARNING: No pong from server 2d1fb2ce-940f-4b60-bf60-39847f31bcaf -
> will consider it dead

The answer to my question is that it doesn't matter "why" it's blocking because it's dead (because it's hit a certain limit).

I'm surprised that Vert.x doesn't handle this more gracefully - like maybe throwing an exception.

Blocking error #1

Thread blocked at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.addListener(FutureImpl.java:140) at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.addListener(PromiseImpl.java:23) at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.onComplete(FutureImpl.java:133) at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23) at io.vertx.core.spi.cluster.impl.selector.Selectors.withSelector(Selectors.java:48) at

Blocking error #2

io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.(CharsetEncoder.java:198)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.(CharsetEncoder.java:233)
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.(UTF_8.java:558)
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.(UTF_8.java:554)
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.newEncoder(UTF_8.java:72)

Blocking error #3

io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ConnectionHolder.writeMessage(ConnectionHolder.java:93)
at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ClusteredEventBus.sendRemote(ClusteredEventBus.java:332)
at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ClusteredEventBus.sendToNode(ClusteredEventBus.java:283)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll be running 100 tasks on the same thread, because Vert.x has thread affinity. If you want to avoid that, run them on separate verticles. But still, I don't think you have 100 CPUs, so there will be a lot of contention.

And setting all of them to execute every 1ms means that they somehow need to finish in 10 microseconds each, which includes networking code, because you're using clustered EventBus.

So, it's how the test is written, not what Vert.x is doing.

If you really want to test this kind of load (we're talking 100K rps here), spread your requests across multiple machines.

But event then, I'm not sure that Hazelcast is build to handle that kind of load.

If you would like to know what really blocks, my guess is this part of code:

https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/spi/cluster/impl/DefaultNodeSelector.java#L43

As I don't have a clustered Vert.x readily setup, I cannot confirm if my assumption is correct, though.

Comment: I'm not sure where Hazelcast comes into this - do you know what code is specifically blocking - I don't think it's Hazelcast? I thought "send" was supposed to be async?

Comment: Alexey is right: try to spread your requests across cores by using multiple injector verticles, and if that's not enough across multiple machines.

Comment: @Alexey : when the address is always the same, the cluster manager is no longer involved: Vert.x caches the destinations and uses its own connections for the transport of messages.

Comment: I'm aware that I can increase performance by scaling - the question is how to use event bus without blocking and why does it only block under high load. Looks like it's not possible to use the event bus without blocking which is different behavior than say WebSockets which even with 1000 timers still doesn't block.

Comment: @Charlie I edited my answer with my suspect, as well as a note on comparison between EventBus and WebSockets. Hope that helps.